# Why is 1 a Powerful Number

Tags: number-theory

1 is listed as a powerful number, but I don't understand how it fits the definition. Although 1 / (1^2), 1 is not a prime. I'm missing something in the definition.

Comment: There are no primes didiving $1$ so the requirement is trivially fulfilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of powerful is *NOT* there exists a prime $p$ that $p|m$ and for every $p|m \implies p^2|m$.

The definition is if $p|m$ then $p^2|m$.  This does *not* mean that there *is* any $p|m$.  If no $p|m$ at all, then it is vacuuously true that all $p$ (all zero of them) that $p|m$ have $p^2|m$.

Another way of looking at it is, in order to *NOT* be powerful there most by some $p$ so that $p|m$ and $p^2\not \mid m$.  For $1$, there is no such prime.

Answer (score 2):

For every prime $p$ that divides $1$, it is true that $p^2$ also divides $1$.

This is a vacuous truth ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth)), since there **are no primes** that divide $1$.